# One more Drawer in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I am newbie in android programming, but I'd like to try any application, I already got Navigation Drawer menu, which shows fragments, but in one of the fragments I want another drawer from right side, is there any way to do it ? I am using ActionBarSherlock. Any help would be good. Thanks :)

Comment: It's good that you set yourself such goals, but I'd suggest you stick to standard UI patterns at first until you know you way around Android a bit. For the same reason, you should try to get along without 3rd party libraries like ActionBarSherlock (which is a very good library, don't get me wrong)

Comment: Check out the answer. Vote-up and mark answer as accepted if it helped.

Comment: @Ridcully is right. You should not jump directly to the external jars or libraries. Firstly checkout what Android has to offer.

Comment: Thanks for responds, I will try the sliding menu, from @johntheripp3r and let you know :) ... It's not big goal in my opinion, Navigation Drawer by ABS wasn't hard, but I've got an idea to do another drawer to fragment, like is on facebook (right side menu), (left side chat/contacts).

Comment: @user2900523 I am using it too.. ;). Its really nice. And please conside to do a vote-up on the answer.

Comment: @user2900523 you can have with the navigation drawer by changing the   `android:layout_gravity="start"` to left i guess for the listview

Comment: @Raghunandan I know, already have android:layout_gravity="left", it works greats if a change it to "right" but I want to open the fragment by Navigation drawer (from right side) and in the fragment which I open I want to open another Drawer (from left side).

Comment: @user2900523 you can use two listviews one for the right and one for the left and change the java code accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sliding menu will solve your problem. 
[gibhub library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) 
There is even a sample app to check it out. 
[google play store](http://bit.ly/TWejze) sample app